# Column titles in a table: singular or plural?

Tags: plural-forms

Should column titles in a table be written in singular or plural form?

E.g. singular:

[image]

plural:

[image]

Comment: Whichever and however you decide, it's advisable to remain consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is largely stylistic. Typically they would be singular. (Name, Address, etc.) However, your "Parameter name" entries have multiple parameters names, so you might show that with the headings:

| **Parameter category** | **Parameter names** |

or: (if there may be any number of parameter names)

| **Parameter category** | **Parameter name(s)** |